# Unable to get callback of android permission when user agrees or rejects in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, android-permissions

I use [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions) to get the camera permission and it work well in iOS.
But I can't get callback of android permission when user agrees or rejects.
I tried replacing it with [PermissionsAndroid](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.66/permissionsandroid) but I had the same issue.

Finally, I created a new project of React Native and using the same code I was able to get callback of android permission. What is the reason for this situation?

Note: Both projects use the same version of React Native.

Comment: :O sounds strange joe, this shouldnt happen. what is the min sdk version for both apps. also do try sharing manifest.xml for both projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my problem came from the use of the onRequestPermissionsResult method in the original Android project, as long as I annotate it everything works fine.

I tried to understand the reason and found out that the previous maintenance project person did not write `super` in `onRequestPermissionsResult`, which caused react native to not call back the result after obtaining the permission.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have this in your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file. If not, then add it and rebuild your app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

2. You can check the status of your permission request and see if it's blocked or granted.

```
import RNPermissions, { PERMISSIONS } from 'react-native-permissions';

const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
  const p = PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA;
  const checkStatus = await RNPermissions.check(p);
  console.log('checkStatus', checkStatus);
  const requestStatus = await RNPermissions.request(p);
  console.log('requestStatus', requestStatus);
};
```

3. It's possible that you might have denied permission the first time, in which case the response to further `request()` will always be `blocked`. In such case you should go app settings and change the permission manually.